# accessing function defined in another class using delegate method

Tags: iphone, uiapplicationdelegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"didselectrowatindexatpath");

Place *placeAtIndex = (Place *)[appDelegate.PlacesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSLog(@"required lat long is %f, %f ", placeAtIndex.PlaceLatitude, placeAtIndex.PlaceLongitude);



returnToMapDelegate = (CortesViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];



[returnToMapDelegate showAddress];  


}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  is Called in PlacesViewController.m and Function "showaddress" is defined in CortesViewController.h.
```

I am getting error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CortesAppDelegate showAddress]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146ce0'"`

at line

```
returnToMapDelegate = (CortesViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

I used successfully following delegate method in code.

```
CortesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CortesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      [appDelegate somefunction] ;
```

But when I tried same thing  for CortesViewController, application crashes. I am new to iOS. It might be possible that I am missing very simple point.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Post implementation of your method `showAddress` in `CortesViewController`

Comment: -(void) showAddress{ region.span.latitudeDelta = current_factor ;
  region.span.longitudeDelta = current_factor ;
  region.center.latitude = current_latitude ;
  region.center.longitude = current_longitude ;
  [mymap setRegion:region animated:TRUE];}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in following: method `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` returns object of class `CortesAppDelegate`. So you cannot call `showAddress` as it is defined in `CortesViewController`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know any method that can be called to access functions in CortesViewController.m?

Comment: You should have reference to object with class `CortesViewController` and then just send that message to that object

Comment: Thanks friend. I created instance of CortesViewController. and passed message to it which worked fine. Thnaks a lot.